# How are polygon "sleeves" called and how are they calculated?

Tags: geometry, polygon

When a polygon gets rotated it skips all possible rotations in between the current and the desired situation. Here are 3 images illustrating what I mean:

This is the current polygon:
[image: current polygon]

Rotating it 45 degrees (in clockwise direction) would result in:
[image: desired polygon]

The current polygon rotated by 45 degrees in clockwise direction, with all possible situations in between would result in:
[image: complete polygon]

How are these "sleeves" (in-between situations) actually called, and how are these "complete polygons" calculated/approximated based on the current polygon and desired angle of rotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the CAD industry, we would call this operation a 2d sweep, or a 2d planar sweep; in this case a 2d planar rotational sweep.  (Not to be confused with a [sweep line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm).)  The resulting area would be the 2d swept area or 2d swept face, and the outline called the 2d swept boundary.

A couple of papers on the topic can be found here:

- [Polygonal boundary approximation for a 2D general sweep based on envelope and boolean operations (2000)](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Fcontent%2Fpdf%2F10.1007%2Fs003710050209.pdf&ei=vJOtVP_LOcbIeNXfgbAE&usg=AFQjCNHs0A9mDF65433tJ_HRJSfZtfdbPQ&bvm=bv.83134100,d.dmo) ([another link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.138.7691), and a [direct PDF Link](http://3map.snu.ac.kr/mskim/ftp/2dsweep.pdf).)
- [Approximate General Sweep Boundary of a 2D Curved Object (1993)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary;jsessionid=426014BEC158ECFB93C6F314ACB5E6A2?doi=10.1.1.30.2424).

Your case of a 2d rotational sweep is not as general as the cases considered in these papers.  If you think about sweeping just a single curve -- a line or an arc, say -- then the boundary curves of the swept area in 2d will as follows.  Imagine sweeping the curve *in 3d*, where the curve is simultaneously extruded along the axis of rotation as it is rotated around the axis.  In that case, the boundaries of your 2d sweep would be the boundaries of the 3d swept surface projected back to 2d *plus the [3d silhouettes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_edge) of the swept surface* projected back into 2d, taking the axis of rotation as the view vector for silhouette creation.

Computing silhouettes of general surfaces is nontrivial, but for a rotational sweep + extrusion along the axis of rotation the silhouettes will be traced out by points where the tangent of the swept curve is parallel to the direction of rotation -- i.e., perpendicular to the radius vector drawn out from the center of rotation.  Thus an algorithm to compute your 2d area might look like:

1. For each edge segment of the area to be rotationally swept,
2. Split the edge where the tangent becomes parallel to the direction of rotation.
3. Exclude any degenerate curves -- arcs that are coaxial with the axis of rotation.
4. For each split edge segment, form a 2d area comprised of the start position of the curve, the end position of the curve, and the start and end points connected by arcs.  Since we split at the silhouette points, there should be no self intersections.
5. Do a [2d boolean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_operations_on_polygons) of the 2d area in its start position, its end position, and the swept areas created in the first steps.